# skew UIView without giving perspective and keeping heigh and width

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform, skew

[image: Skew Example]
Hi,

I am trying to achieve a transformation like in the image but I only have got a similar transformation but with perspective (which I don't want) using CGATransform3D. How could I achieve this using objective-c? The transformed image should have the same heigh and width than the original but with the base tilted by a given angle.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use Core Image for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a “shear” or “skew” transformation. Luckily for you, shear transformations are affine transformations, and iOS supports affine transformations at both the `UIView` and `CALayer` levels. However, it has no convenience functions to construct shear transforms, so let's write one:

```
static CGAffineTransform affineTransformMakeShear(CGFloat xShear, CGFloat yShear) {
    return CGAffineTransformMake(1, yShear, xShear, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

It's not obvious exactly what `xShear` and `yShear` mean. `xShear` is the tangent of the angle by which the y-axis is skewed, and `yShear` is the tangent of the angle by which the x-axis is skewed. This may seem backwards, but it has the visual effect you expect: a non-zero `xShear` tilts the figure left or right, and a non-zero `yShear` tilts the figure up or down.

Since tan π/4 = 1 (or, if you prefer, tan 45° = 1), the transform returned by `affineTransformMakeShear(1, 0)` turns a rectangle into a parallelogram whose left and right edges are at π/4 radians (or 45°).

Demo:

[image: shear demo]

Note that shearing on both axes can be identical to the combination of a rotation and a scale.

Here's my demo code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *shearedView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *verticalShearSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *horizontalShearSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *verticalShearLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *horizontalShearLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateAppearance:nil];
}

static CGAffineTransform affineTransformMakeShear(CGFloat xShear, CGFloat yShear) {
    return CGAffineTransformMake(1, yShear, xShear, 1, 0, 0);
}

- (IBAction)updateAppearance:(id)sender {
    CGFloat xShear = self.horizontalShearSlider.value;
    CGFloat yShear = self.verticalShearSlider.value;
    self.shearedView.transform = affineTransformMakeShear(xShear, yShear);
    self.horizontalShearLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", xShear];
    self.verticalShearLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", yShear];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this is awesome and easier than i thought! :D

Comment: @rob you have the best demos dude  :) it would be cool if someone changed these classics to Swift one day...

Comment: @rob mayoff i still don't understand, how to provide angle value in radians or degrees?

Comment: Pass `tan(angle)` to `affineTransformMakeShear`.

Comment: Interesting note: while UIView is being transformed based off its center, CGRect is transformed based of its top left vertex.

Comment: What has affineTransformMakeShear been renamed in Swift 6? The compiler says No ;-) and can't find any references.

Comment: There is no Swift 6 yet (and probably won't be for the next several years). Also, `affineTransformMakeShear` is a function defined in this answer. It has never been part of the iOS SDK.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to humour you. We're on 5.5.1 so there is hope. And apologies for not reading the opening bit of your exceptionally well documented answer.

Answer (score 0):

@[Fattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/fattie).
Quick Swift version of Rob's demo:

```
class AffineTester: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var shearedView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalShearSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalShearSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalShearLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalShearLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateAppearance(self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func updateAppearance(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let xShear = CGFloat(horizontalShearSlider.value)
        let yShear = CGFloat(verticalShearSlider.value)
        shearedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(1, yShear, xShear, 1, 0, 0)
        horizontalShearLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", xShear)
        verticalShearLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", yShear)
    }
}
```